# UITableViewController Inside UINavigationController and UITabBarController Bottom Inset Off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UINavigationController` that's inside a `UITabBarController`. There is a view on the bottom (I'll call it bottomView) between the table view and the tab bar that needs to stay at the bottom as the table view scrolls, so I can't put it as a footer in the table view.

The issue is that when i scroll to the bottom of the table view, there is an empty space the same height as the tab bar between the lowest content (and the scroll bar) and the top of bottomView.

I think this is because the table view is trying to automatically compensate for the tab view at the bottom, but I can't position it all the way at the bottom because of bottomView.

here's my IB layout:

[image]

and the display (last `tableViewCell` highlighted):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you need to set a contentInset to your tableView like this:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,44,0)];
```

**Edit:**

Ok I think I got it. Set:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your second line works to fix the bottom issue, but I'd still like it to automatically adjust the insets for the nag bar at the top. Do I just need to do that manually?

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm after I added

    `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;`
    `[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];`
    `[self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this same nav controller->tab bar->tableview situation frustratingly cause the tableview to partially overlap with the navigation bar, instead of not reaching the tab bar. To anyone having this issue when using a UITableView: ensure your navigation bar is not translucent. If you want to use this setup with a translucent navigation bar, select the UITabBarController in the Interface Builder and uncheck the "extend edges under top bars" option in the attributes inspector.